# IIS Root redirect to subfolder with HTTPS and SSL certification

Tags: https, url-rewriting, iis

I need to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a subdirectory. Currently all requests that go to `http://example.org` needs to be redirected to `https://example.org/subdirectory`. As an example: `https://example.org/subdirectory` needs to redirect to the root directory.

I'm using IIS v10 and also installed URL Rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following rewrite rules in web.config file and check.

```
<system.webServer> <rewrite>
    <rules>
     <clear />
          <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
              </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/subdirectory" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
         </rule>
    </rules>
 </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```